# Minimum Required SDK - Percentages

Tags: android, sdk, operating-system, percentage

Does anyone know what percentage of consumers use each operating system for Android?

When choosing the minimum required SDK, you of course want to target the largest audience possible, but lose as few of the programming updates as possible.  For example, while v2.2 may have a wide audience, there are certain features that cannot be used in the program.  But using v4.2 will give you every feature available, but who knows how many people actually have the most up to date version.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone know what percentage of consumers use each operating system for Android?

This is shown on the [Device Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) and is reported by damn near every Android blog in existence.

Here, for example, is the just-updated May pie chart:

[image: Android OS usage, as of May 2013]

Note, though, that these dashboards are based on Play Store accesses, and therefore do not count devices that lack the Play Store (e.g., Kindle Fire).

Comment: Do you know where their line graph went that showed the previous percentages as well?  **Edit: [Android version history graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)**

Comment: @Grant: Yeah, I noticed that was missing today. Not sure if that's a page generation bug, some other problem, or an intentional drop.